# what is the type of back_inserter(container)

Tags: c++, types

My following code compiles but I do not know how to write this without using decltype. I have written my failed attempts in commented lines below the line which uses decltype.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class Out>
class Fill{
public:
  Fill(){}
  void fill(Out x){
    for(int i = 0; i != 10; i++)*x++ = i;
  }
};

int main(){
  vector<int> v;

  Fill<decltype(back_inserter(v))> f; //works

  //does not work
  //Fill<vector<int>::iterator> g;

  //does not work
  //Fill<back_insert_iterator<vector<int>> h;


  f.fill(back_inserter(v));
  copy(v.begin(),v.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
}
```

Thanks

suresh

Answer (score 2):

The type will be `back_insert_iterater<vector<int> >`. Your 3rd example doesn't work because you need a whitespace between the ">>". See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/back_insert_iterator/, it simply holds a pointer to the container type and redefines operator= to be container.push_back. I believe this is present so that std containers can work with std algorithms. But, since you have control the definition to Fill you could simply allow the Fill class to hold a container pointer and call push_back directly against the container.

Comment: Even with the right angle brackets close by as you suggested, I get compile error as:   `error: template argument 1 is invalid`. I was using g++ 4.4 with `-std=c++0x` option. That's why I kept the right angled brackets together. My requirement is to write a function which would just accept an output iterator and populate it as seen in STL `copy` algorithms etc. So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<int> ints;
typedef back_insert_iterator<vector<int>> InserterType; // This is what you need.
Fill<InserterType> f;
f.fill(back_inserter(ints));
copy(ints.begin(), ints.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: In my original post, one right angled bracket was missing and hence compiler was giving error messages..Stupid mistake....the corrected line is given below and now the code compiles correctly!!!

    `Fill<back_insert_iterator<vector<int>>> h;`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using c++0x, the answer is: 'auto' :D

Comment: I just wanted to know what the actual type is. I managed with `decltype` but wanted to know the exact type!

Comment: @fileoffset did you try that ? I don't think Fill<auto> f; does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the mistake in my original post was that I missed the 3rd right angled bracket in the definition of `h`. It should be corrected as

```
Fill<back_insert_iterator<vector<int>>> h;
```

Now the code would compile and work as intended.